# Is it possible to make sandwhich aliases?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm looking for a way to make the following alias work for any file name.

```
alias dim='cd /home/jason/Documents; vim *the desired file*; cd'
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I could change this alias to make it so that I could type in any file name as such:

```
dim *the desired file*
```

And still get the same result.
Basically is there a way to call whatever is typed after the alias name into the alias itself?
Something like:

```
alias dim='cd /home/jason/Documents; vim <what is typed after alias>; cd'
```

Comment: // , What was the purpose of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not do that using shell aliases. You need to use a function.

Here is a simple function to do the job :

```bsh
dim() {
cd /home/jason/Documents
vim "$1"
cd
}
```

The function `dim` will take a file name as argument. You can put this code snippet at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file and then run it as:

```
dim file.txt
```

Replace `file.txt` with any file name you want.

To run it from the current shell session, `source` the `~/.bashrc` file first :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: What does the "$1" signify? I'm a beginner and trying to learn rather than just copy paste and call it a day.

Comment: @JasonBasanese I appreciate your decision :) `$1` indicates the first positional parameter or argument to the function..think of it as a way of giving input to a function or script ..like all programming languages `bash` also uses this....you'll find numerous resources about this on Google..

Answer (score 3):

Not with aliases, use functions instead.

From the [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **ALIASES**
>
> [...] There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see **FUNCTIONS** below).

So your function could be:

> function dim () { cd ~jason/Documents ; vim $* ; cd - ;}

Comment: Wouldn't ~/Documents work just fine in this case? Also what do the $ and * symbols mean in this case? and is the - after the cd needed? Usually I can just type cd and it goes up a directory.

Comment: “Usually I can just type cd and it goes up a directory” – I only know a plain `cd` to bring you to your home directory; `cd ..` goes one level up. `cd -` brings you to the previous directory from which you `cd`’ed.

Comment: @JasonBasanese: Yes ~/Documents would work for everyone (if it is a function for all users). `$*` is like `$1 $2 $3...` just to give the whole list to vim, not the first argument you type. And as Chriki said, `cd -` will return to the previous directory (the one you were when you invoked the function).